# How to avoid Visual Studio 2013 firing UserControl's constructor when editing Windows Form in Design Mode?

Tags: constructor, user-controls, visual-studio-2013, designmode

My project is a Windows Application, targeting .NET Framework 4.5., referencing *EntityFramework 6.1.1*.

My main form has a *UserControl*, which has a second usercontrol within. The nested *UserControl* constructor has something similar to:

```
public ucNestedUserControl()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   listAll();
}
```

`listAll` is a method which pulls loads data from *SQL Server* database tables (using *EntityFramework*).

I did some minor changes in database (removed delete cascade from some relationships), and after opening my project and double clicking (step 1) the main *Windows Form* in *Solution Explorer*, I noticed that *Visual Studio* is firing the nested *UserControl* constructor (step 2) and reading the database records with `listAll` method.

[image]

How can I avoid this nested *UserControl* constructor from loading/connecting to database while in *design mode*? Is this Visual Studio 2013 default behavior?

[image]

Comment: You can't.  Use the DesignMode property to prevent code from running in design mode.

Comment: @Hans it could be a valid answer. It seems this piece of code is working: `public static bool IsInDesignMode() { return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Contains("VisualStudio"); }`